# Is it possible to print directly on a plastic stand up pouch?

Tags: print-design

I am about to start my roasted coffee company an intend to package the coffee in a plastic stand up pouch. I am working on my design, but would prefer to print the design directly on the bag itself.

Is it possible to print on a plastic bag without damaging the zip lock or sticking the inside of the bag together?

Comment: This seems like a shopping request, not a question focused on Graphic Design

Comment: @Khadrie: I've edited your question to better fit our site. If you think I've changed the meaning of your question too much, feel free to revert my [edit] or elaborate it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Normally the printing of a bag needs to be done before the bag is fabricated. (for example with flexography you print a roll of plastic, which then it is cutted, sealed and the zip is added)

But that depends on the amount of bags.

If you have just a few hundreds you could see if silk print works for you.